# How do I run applications as if they were being run by an active windows user? OpenSSH Server

Tags: python, windows, virtual-machine, openssh

So I've setup an OpenSSH server inside of a windows virtual machine, and I've connected to the user I want to control e.g

> ssh user@ip_adress

And I want to run for example a python program, notepad or anything else as if it was executed by the user I have open on my virtual machine.

How would I achieve this? Currently it's running things in its own instance without gui, and modifying files etc. does seem to sync.

The use case I need is running a python application that needs access to the screen & needs to send key/mouse inputs etc.

I've tried PsExec to run things, but I can't seem to get it working either?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it will not be that easy. By default `ssh` only open a bi-directional stream which if fine for command line applications or at most for *full screen terminal application* like vi. It has built-in features to transport a X11 desktop, but Windows uses a different protocol which is RDP.

If the client machine is also a Windows machine, it is still fairly easy, because `ssh` allows *port forwarding*: you map a local port on your machine to a remote port on the server. The configuration actually depends on the client software, but for the excellent PUTTY, you can configure it through the menu.
One this is done, you connect you local remote desktop client to that local port, and you will get a remote desktop of the server. Now you can use any GUI application on the server.

If the client machine is a Unix-like (Linux), then you will have to find a RDP client. You could Google for KRDC, Remmina, rdesktop or xfreerdp...

---

Of course if no firewall exists between the client and the server, you should just bypass the ssh tunnel and directly connect to the RDP port on the server machine (by default it should be 3389)...

Comment: The thing is I don't want to stream anything back to my client machine (Linux) I just want to execute commands as if they where executed inside of the virtual machine directly. Because I already have it running as a virtual machine so I can see the user's screen etc.

Comment: @ZeddGrayhem: if you already have an access to the virtual machine screen what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to execute things from my SSH connection as if they're being executed as the user logged into the virtual machine. So e.g I have remote vscode open (which establishes an SSH connection) and I write a program that displays a window, or that captures the screen on the virtual machine, and then I want to run it as the active user through that connection.